Counterexample for: $E(X | Y, Z) = f(Y)$ implies that $X$ independent of $Z$ given $Y$?
I am looking for a nice counterexample of the statement: if $\mathbb{E}(X | Y, Z) = f(Y)$ for a measurable function $f$ implies that $X$ is independent of $Z$ given $Y$, i.e. $X \perp Z | Y$.
Any help is appreciated.

Let $Z$ and $T$ be independent uniform on $\{-1, 1\}$, $Y = 0$ and $X = T(Z + 1)$.
Then $\mathbb E(X | Y, Z = 1) = \mathbb E(2T | Y, Z = 1) = 0$ and $\mathbb E(X | Y, Z = -1) = \mathbb E(0 | Y, Z = 1) = 0$, but $P(X = 2 | Z = 1, Y = 0) = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0 = P(X = 2 | Z = -1, Y = 0)$.

I don't follow $\mathbb{E}(X|Y, Z) = 0$ -- I calculate that it is uniform on ${-1.5, 1.5}$.

I agree with @hunter, this conditional expectation is $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y,Z] = \frac{3}{2} Z$

Yes, sorry, we need zero expectation from component independent of $Z$, not from $Z$ itself. Updated.

@mihaild Thank you very much, this looks correct to me. To hunter?

yes looks great!

You could expand this example to allow any distribution for $Y$ independent of $Z$ and $T$, and use any $f(Y)$, by letting $X=T(Z+1)+f(Y)$
